# Getting rid of ANSI escape characters when viewing ri in (Mac)Vim

Tags: ruby, vim, special-characters, macvim, ri

I'm having trouble viewing ri documentation within gvim and MacVim (tried it on both) Some of the ri documentation includes text decorations that look fine when viewed in a terminal window, but include ANSI escape characters when viewing in gvim/MacVim. For example, the following ri snippet from `$ri class` looks like this in the terminal:

> Returns the class of **obj**, now
>   preferred over **Object#type**

And this in gvim:

> Returns the class of [4mobj[m, now preferred over [7mObject#type[m,

It'd be great to be able to reference legible ri docs within gvim. Any ideas on where to begin looking to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `ri` like this:

```
ri --format=rdoc
```

AFAIK, the `rdoc` format is plain text so you won't have to filter out the ANSI escape sequences.

You can probably get "real" plain text by making a shell script like this:

```
ri --format=bs $@ | sed 's:.^H::g'
```

Where `^H` is a raw <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> (or whatever backspace is for you), then call that shell script instead of `ri`.

Comment: Interesting solution! It *sort of* works, but it trades ANSI escape sequences for html tags. For example, the above becomes `Returns the class of <em>Obj</em>, now preferred over <tt>Object#type</tt>...`

Comment: You could try `--format=bs`, that'll use old-school backspace formatting (pipe the output into `cat -v` and you'll see the backspaces) and that'll be easier to filter than ANSI escape sequences. Why there isn't a `--format=plain` for plain text is a mystery.

Comment: i think this is the best bet. the annoying thing is it used to not be a problem in ruby 1.8. seems to be specific to 1.9. also, piping the output to `col -b` removes backspace characters, and is a little cleaner than sed.

Comment: Nice one with the `col -b`, I think I've forgotten most of the neat little shell scripting tools like that.

Comment: is there any way to scroll thru the output? like less/more do

Comment: @Cezar: He's viewing the content inside vim so I'm not sure what you mean, I'm more of shell guy than a vim guy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

These two scripts seem to have been written to address that problem. They don't appear to be perfect solutions. One of them apparently requires a patch to vi, or did at one point. I can't quite tell what the other one does but I think it renders your window, interpreting the codes, when you use a specific command.

There is also some advice on existing vi commands.

See:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302
- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1127