# MacVim Command Window text coloring help (Rspec output)

Tags: ruby, vim, rspec, macvim

I'm trying to transition to MacVim for ruby dev.  One of the hangups I have is running specs quickly and getting results (passes/failures) easily.

When I run `:Rake` (or `:!rspec %`) it runs the specs in the current file.  The output is shown in the command window.

If I run this in regular Terminal, I get colored output.  That is, the dots are green and the failures are red.

In MacVim, I get these weird `[32m` and `[0m` tokens.  Here's an example:
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [vim-rspec](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec). It'll give you the clean, nicely colored rspec output you're after:

[image: rspec output in MacVim]

BTW, those are ANSI escape sequences messing up the output. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732042/getting-rid-of-ansi-escape-characters-when-viewing-ri-in-macvim) for a question I asked a few weeks ago about getting rid of them while viewing ri documentation in (Mac|g)vim. Bottom line: it's easier to try to get plain text output than to try and shoehorn support for ANSI escape sequences into Vim.

Answer (score 3):

Gvim (and I assume Macvim is just that with a brand-name :) ) doesn't have a real terminal behind it, so that's why you're getting these 'weird' tokens - they are the escape codes a real terminal would interpret as colors.

As michaelmichael points out, getting vim to like ANSI escape codes is bothersome. Also, I like his suggestion of vim-rspec. I cobbled this (https://github.com/dahu/VimTestRunner) together as a lightweight rspec test runner. It shows a red/green bar in your Vim status line when you run the tests. You can run just the rspec associated with the current file using `<leader>y` or all rspecs in the current directory with `<leader>a`. Feedback and suggestions for improvement welcome. Oh, and it's quite alpha at this stage. Be gentle. :-)

Comment: with all of Vim's customizability, I was thinking that this could be fixed to show correct output.  No?